# Base convert in python given a string

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, radix

In PHP, given a string value (*integers separated by chars*), we can calculate its integer representation:

```
$hashable = "123A123"; // notice "A" delim
$hash_int = base_convert($hashable, 11, 10);
echo $hash_int;
```

Output

```
2151042
```

It's useful because result is unique for huge range of strings (short ones, of course). I use it for ID generation in my application.

How can we do same conversions in python? Is it possible to generate equal integers for same strings in both PHP and python?

Maybe first we need to take *hash int* of `hashable` *string* and then convert the base of integer but how exactly we do this?

Comment: what is it's integer representation?

Comment: Updated original question. I am not sure but the code returns 0 if `hashable` has no integers. I am not sure where and how conversion happens in php.

Comment: i dont even understand how that convert would work, `z` is not in `base11`...? would base11 only include `a` to represent 11

Comment: PHP internally converts string to number before base conversion, that's all i guess.

Comment: `194472 == base11(123123)` so it looks like it ignores anything that isnt a valid character.

Comment: besides that, you can convert from any base to base10 with `int(str,base=num)` then you can do something like [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65212-convert-from-decimal-to-any-base-number/) to convert that decimal into another base

Comment: @RNar You're correct. Tested, confirmed.. Looks like it ignores non-numerics. Surprise for me.

Comment: all non-numerics? depending on the base (greater than base 10), there should be some letters that are accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previously suggested method will fail for binary and many other conversions, this will go from any base  from 2 to 36 and return 0 for invalid strings as per the [php implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php), the php implementation does not ignore letters in the output unless you give invalid input for the base and then it tries to find just the digits and convert so you also cannot return an int as you can and will get letters in the output:

```
def to_base(n, bse):
    digs = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    tmp = []
    while n:
        n, i = divmod(n, bse)
        tmp.append(digs[i])
    return "".join(tmp[::-1])



def chng_frm_base(s, frm_bse, to_bse):
    if to_bse < 2 or to_bse > 36 or frm_bse < 2 or frm_bse > 36:
        raise ValueError("bases must be between 2-36")
    try:
        return to_base(int(s, frm_bse), to_bse)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            n = int("".join([ch for ch in s if ch.isdigit()]),frm_bse)
            return to_base(n, to_bse)
        except ValueError:
            return 0
```

Output:

```
In [13]: chng_frm_base("123A123", 11, 10)
Out[13]: '2151042'

In [14]: chng_frm_base("123A123", 11, 8)
Out[14]: '10151202'

In [15]: chng_frm_base("123A123", 11, 2)
Out[15]: '1000001101001010000010'

In [16]: chng_frm_base("123A123", 11, 35)
Out[16]: '1f5xc'

In [17]: chng_frm_base("123A123", 11, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-9776e0abca26> in <module>()
----> 1 chng_frm_base("123A123", 11, 1)

<ipython-input-2-9c00d800545d> in chng_frm_base(s, frm_bse, to_bse)
     10 def chng_frm_base(s, frm_bse, to_bse):
     11     if to_bse < 2 or to_bse > 36 or frm_bse < 2 or frm_bse > 36:
---> 12         raise ValueError("bases must be between 2-36")
     13     try:
     14         return (to_base(int(s, frm_bse), to_bse))

ValueError: bases must be between 2-36

In [18]: chng_frm_base("hello world!", 10, 2)
Out[18]: 0
```

Which if you run the same examples using php outputs the same values for all.

Comment: This is a considerably more comprehensive answer, but still doesn't behave the same as my local PHP install: `$hashable = "123z123"; $hash_int = base_convert($hashable, 11, 10); echo $hash_int; 194472`

Comment: @davejagoda. try it now

Comment: `chng_frm_base` is a terrible name for a function