# Convert decimal to ternary(base3) in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a decimal number ternary in a python function. My idea was to keep dividing until the quotient and remainder were equal, but I can't seem to get that to work. Here's my code:

```
l = 1


#problem code
def ternary(n):
    e = n/3
    q = n%3
    e= n/3
    q= e%3
    print q

r = input("What number should I convert?: ")
k = bin(r)
v = hex(r)
i = oct(r)
print k+"(Binary)"
print v+"(Hex)"
print i+"(Octals)"
ternary(r)
l+=1
# Variables:
#l,r,k,v,i 
#n,q,e
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: Your function calculates `e` and `q` twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: It should keep dividing until I get 0quo and zero rem-- e.g:  10/3, 3quo and 1rem etc until we reach 0quo and 0rem

Comment: *I can't seem to get that to work* - why not? Are there errors? What are your expected inputs and outputs? `input` returns a string...  Are you getting an error indicating that?

Comment: Use divmod like the  `to_base` function here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33802414/2141635

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Can you give an example of how it works and how to use it

Comment: @Sidsy, `to_base(123, 3)` will give you base3 for 123 i.e `'11120'`
,  just apply the same logic

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> My idea was to keep dividing until the quotient and remainder were equal, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Yeah, something like that. Essentially, you want to keep dividing by 3, and collect the remainders. The remainders then make up the final number. In Python, you can use `divmod` to divide and collect the remainder.

```
def ternary (n):
    if n == 0:
        return '0'
    nums = []
    while n:
        n, r = divmod(n, 3)
        nums.append(str(r))
    return ''.join(reversed(nums))
```

Examples:

```
>>> ternary(0)
'0'
>>> ternary(1)
'1'
>>> ternary(2)
'2'
>>> ternary(3)
'10'
>>> ternary(12)
'110'
>>> ternary(22)
'211'
```

Comment: If I wanted to write "(ternary)" next to it, would I  make the final line(minus return) a variable and add the string"(Ternary)" to it, then return that?

Comment: Yeah that would work, but you could also just add a `+ ' (ternary)'` directly at the end of the `return` line.

Comment: nums can be a string. You can achieve this with nums = str(r) + o and return o

Comment: @ForbiddenDuck When concatenating dynamic strings, [using `str.join()` is preferred](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-many-strings-together) over simply adding the strings since the latter will create multiple temporary string objects.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the implementation of NumPy:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.base_repr.html?highlight=base_repr#numpy.base_repr

Though, I agree that a function for ternary exclusively is faster.

```py
import numpy as np

number=100 # decimal
ternary=np.base_repr(number,base=3)
print(ternary)
#10201
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Is this faster than other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 10):

This can also be done with recursion.

```
def ternary(n):
    e = n//3
    q = n%3
    if n == 0:
        return '0'
    elif e == 0:
        return str(q)
    else:
        return ternary(e) + str(q)
```

More generally, you can convert to any base `b` (where `2<=b<=10`) with the following recursive function.

```
def baseb(n, b):
    e = n//b
    q = n%b
    if n == 0:
        return '0'
    elif e == 0:
        return str(q)
    else:
        return baseb(e, b) + str(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nonrecursive solution. It returns a little-endian array of integers, and it works for any natural numbered value and any natural numbered base≥2.

```py
def base(b,n):
    size = math.ceil(math.log(max(1,n),b))
    return [place
        for i in range(size,-1,-1)
        if (place := n//b**i%b) or i<size] or [0]
```

The last `if` statement can be omitted if you don't mind the occasional zero padded answer such as [0,1,0,0,0].

Here is an example of its usage:

```py
>>>base(3,7)
[2,1]
```

Here is its inverse:

```py
def debase(b,x):
    return sum([xi*b**i 
        for i,xi in enumerate(reversed(x))])
```

And here is a test for its behavior:

```
assert all([
    debase(b,base(b,n))==n
    for b in range(2,16+1)
    for n in range(0,1024+1)])
```

Comment: It's better now, although for example for `base(2, 2251799813685247)` you do produce a leading zero. (That number is 2^51-1.)

Comment: Suggestion: divide *first*: `n//b**i%b`. And the `>0` isn't necessary.