# How do you convert hexadecimal to ternary in Python?

Tags: python, hex, ternary

I'm trying to convert any length hexadecimal to ternary (two way), specifically in Python. I've tried using `int`, and that didn't work. I also tried this library called [baseconvert](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/baseconvert), but that just spits an error, `NameError: name 'base' is not defined`, when I try to use the `base` command they give.

Then, I tried this script:

```
#!/usb/bin/python

def toStr(n,base):
   convertString = "0123456789ABCDEF"
   if n < base:
      return convertString[n]
   else:
      return toStr(n//base,base) + convertString[n%base]

#####################

hex = "6a48f82d8e828ce82b82abc12397812389721389712387912321387913248723081270243872308472384723472304723089547230485728347283470928347087230457340587304857034570345708345034509348509834509834598230948230948203948092348092348092348092385409283092340923409823490823409820394820934809234809abababababab2345098234092349084238903244444444444444444444444444444442430898888888888888888888999999999999999999999997"
# hex = "6A48F82D8E828CE82B82"
# hex = "e30ac3baf3ab3ffedb8a02dfcc962e2c455650c1614d63ba9a058685da6f04f1c282a5214e65a47506d65a7b9a80d85fc7365aabce539a0696ff2157485d720a7368613531323a20646333656537636164333839396538333839316236376137376136356531356362346665383262356465646363623631373237383833633761306232663064366630396461643264316461393937336432663134333338393161653264373534623864316363653835656433656635353865363634626665656135373531363820696e6465782e68746d6c"

print("hex  =", hex)

# dec = int(hex, 16)
# print("dec  =", dec)

tern = (toStr(int(hex, 16),3))
print("tern =", tern)

rehex = (toStr(int(tern, 3),16))
print("rehex  =", rehex)

#####################


# unhex: Convert Hexadecits to Trits
# tern = ""
# for i in hex:
#     digit = (toStr(int(i, 16),3))
#     tern += digit
#     # print("tern =", tern)

#     # print(i)
# print("tern =", tern)
```

Which does it two-way, but shows this error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`. I want to have *any* length, so I can't just increase the maximum recursion depth, because that still won't work with *every* length.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559663/convert-decimal-to-ternarybase3-in-python?

Comment: I don't think recursivity is an ideal path if you don't want to exeed the limit, you should try using a loop instead

Comment: Unrelated but your `NameError: name 'base' is not defined` is fixed by either `import baseconvert` , `baseconvert.base("4080.5", 10, 16, string=True)` or `from baseconvert import *` , `base("4080.5", 10, 16, string=True)`. Apparently the doc writer assumed everyone is using that last syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works as expected, and does what you want it to do. The problem is that Python by default has a guard for maximum recursion depth (maximum 1000 layers in stack). You can increase it, but this would not be very scalable. What you really want to do is rewrite your code in an iterative fashion.

Your code could look something like that:

```
def toStr(n, base):
    convertString = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    result = ''
    while n > base:
        result = result + convertString[n%base]
        n = n//base
    if n > 0:
        result = result + convertString[n]
    return result
```

More info: [SO description on max recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3323013/3606192)