# Is it possible to change number systems in python?

Tags: python, number-systems

This may sound similar to many other questions, but I couldn't find an answer to mine. I'm wondering if you can switch the number system of any number. For example,

```
x = 10
y = int(10, 3)
```

How can I switch x into a base-3 number system? This is the solution I've seen but it hasn't worked. I know that for binary, decimal, and hexadecimal systems there is a separate function but I don't know of anything for other number systems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973685/python-homework-converting-any-base-to-any-base

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884219/11070463, here's a function that will return a string representation of a decimal number in any base you want:

```
def baseb(n, b):
    e = n//b
    q = n%b
    if n == 0:
        return '0'
    elif e == 0:
        return str(q)
    else:
        return baseb(e, b) + str(q)
```

```
>>> baseb(10,3)
'101'
```

Better yet, you can use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.base_repr(10, 3)
'101'
```

Comment: If you are going to link to another answer, then this should be closed as a duplicate, don't copy it here

Answer (score -1):

```
math.log(yournumber,basenumber)
```

Can you try this one?